# ¿Cómo debo validar que mi respuesta acepte mayúsculas o minúsculas indistintamente?

Tags: java

Necesito capturar BTC o btc, ETH o eth, ... Leí que se puede usar "equals" o "ignorecase" pero no entiendo como debo hacer la validación.

```
Monedas moneda = new Monedas();
System.out.println("Ingrese el tipo de criptomoneda");
System.out.println("BTC, ETH, XRP, DOGE");
moneda.setCriptomoneda(sn.next());
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Los métodos que se pueden utilizar en java para comprobar si una letra está en mayúcula o minúsucula, es:

```
public static boolean esMayuscula(String s) {
    return s.equals(s.toUpperCase());
}

public static boolean esMinuscula(String s) {
    return s.equals(s.toLowerCase());
}
```

Para aceptar cualquier texto, sea en minúsuculas o mayúsculas, podrías usar la validación:

```
cadena.equalsIgnoreCase("abc");
```

Comment: Otra opción es convertir directamente la cadena de entrada a mayúsculas o minúsculas y a partir de ahí continuar sabiendo que el valor ya va estar en que formato está.

Answer (score 1):

Gracias por sus respuestas, el código quedó así :

```
public void setCriptomoneda(String criptomoneda) {
this.criptomoneda = criptomoneda.toUpperCase();
```

Cree un método y allí convierto la entrada a mayúsculas, así que aunque escriban la palabra en minúsculas el sistema la trata como mayúsculas y puedo realizar el resto de las operaciones. Gracias por sus comentarios.